# Set a column value to a subquery result

Tags: sql, string, subquery, alias

not sure if my search is wrong or what but I'm turning up no results , Basically I have the following sql query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ClientID, EventType, EventDescription,EventTime AS
                      (SELECT     SUBSTRING(EventTime, 0, 12))
 FROM         EventLog
 WHERE     (EventType = 'Gig')
```

I want to have it so that the column EventTime is a substring of the actual value

Could someone show me how to do this as the above query won't execute, apologies if this is an obvious question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ClientID, EventType, EventDescription,
                SUBSTRING(EventTime, 0, 12) as EventTime                           
FROM         EventLog
WHERE     (EventType = 'Gig')
```